# Spring start up slow - types not cached on startup in DefaultListableBeanFactory

Tags: spring

We currently use Spring 4.0.9

Our web application is getting slower and slower at starting up, gone from 200 seconds to 600 seconds over the last few months.

I've done some analysis and the biggest issue is the method...

```
public String[] getBeanNamesForType(Class<?> type, boolean includeNonSingletons, boolean allowEagerInit)
```

... in the ***org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory*** class

Developers are using @Autowired more and more to wire in their dependencies. It seems on startup (when the bean factories are being constructed) that getBeanNamesForType iterates through the entire bean name list looking for appropriate types. If you have many beans like we do (1400) this method call is taking over 0.5 seconds to complete for autowiring one property in a bean. So you can imagine that is a lot of time being wasted.

I can see previous fixes have been put into DefaultListableBeanFactory so when creating and autowiring non-singleton beans at runtime, it is very quick since the bean names are cached by type

See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6870

However this caching behaviour is only available once the bean factories have all been initialized so you still get the same problem on application startup.

I'm looking at the code but it is quite involved. I'm wondering if there is a way we can cache bean names against type as the bean factory is constructed. As a quick test I modified the code of DefaultListableBeanFactory from...

```
  @Override
  public String[] getBeanNamesForType(Class<?> type, boolean includeNonSingletons, boolean allowEagerInit) {
    if (!isConfigurationFrozen() || type == null || !allowEagerInit) {
      return doGetBeanNamesForType(type, includeNonSingletons, allowEagerInit);
    }
    Map<Class<?>, String[]> cache =
        (includeNonSingletons ? this.allBeanNamesByType : this.singletonBeanNamesByType);
    String[] resolvedBeanNames = cache.get(type);
    if (resolvedBeanNames != null) {
      return resolvedBeanNames;
    }
    resolvedBeanNames = doGetBeanNamesForType(type, includeNonSingletons, allowEagerInit);
    if (ClassUtils.isCacheSafe(type, getBeanClassLoader())) {
      cache.put(type, resolvedBeanNames);
    }
    return resolvedBeanNames;
  }
```

...to...

```
  @Override
  public String[] getBeanNamesForType(Class<?> type, boolean includeNonSingletons, boolean allowEagerInit) {
    if (!isConfigurationFrozen() || type == null || !allowEagerInit) {
      Map<Class<?>, String[]> cache =
        (includeNonSingletons ? this.allBeanNamesByType1 : this.singletonBeanNamesByType1);
      String[] resolvedBeanNames1 = cache.get(type);
      if (resolvedBeanNames1 != null) {
        return resolvedBeanNames1;
      }
      resolvedBeanNames1 = doGetBeanNamesForType(type, includeNonSingletons, allowEagerInit);
      if (ClassUtils.isCacheSafe(type, getBeanClassLoader())) {
        cache.put(type, resolvedBeanNames1);
      }
      return resolvedBeanNames1;
    }
    Map<Class<?>, String[]> cache =
        (includeNonSingletons ? this.allBeanNamesByType : this.singletonBeanNamesByType);
    String[] resolvedBeanNames = cache.get(type);
    if (resolvedBeanNames != null) {
      return resolvedBeanNames;
    }
    resolvedBeanNames = doGetBeanNamesForType(type, includeNonSingletons, allowEagerInit);
    if (ClassUtils.isCacheSafe(type, getBeanClassLoader())) {
      cache.put(type, resolvedBeanNames);
    }
    return resolvedBeanNames;
  }
```

Basically all I am doing is caching the types on the fly. This seems to work and allows our application to start twice as quick.

However I am aware my quick test does not take into account all Spring scenarios. There must be reason the entire bean definition list is checked each time?

Any ideas?